# dropdown box vs dropdown background

Tags: css, menu, navigation

I am having some issue with the dropdown menu.
So I decided to reduce the height of the lines in dropdown list. but 2 other issues came:
1. the background that shows on hover still didn't reduce the size.
2. dropdown item didn't allign in center of the line.

Please help.
Thank you all in advance.

[image]

this is the css code I am using in Blogspot:

```
  #nav ul ul li {
min-width: 180px;
background-color: #333333;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;

}
```

Comment: share your html or snippet/fiddle would be much better.

Comment: Problem is I am new with this and using a template that is not mine. So honestly I really have no idea of what to post now @@